# Why do I get an error when I bundle install a bootstrap-sass gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Resolving dependencies...

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":

In Gemfile:

bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.6) x86-mingw32 depends on
     sass (>= 3.3.4) x86-mingw32

sass-rails (>= 3.2) x86-mingw32 depends on
     sass (3.2.19)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the version specification from the `sass-rails` gem and trying again?

Comment: I solved it by not specifying the bootstrap-sass gem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your other gems so I can't be sure, but I suspect you've got another gem there that requires the sass-rails gem to be at version 4.0.3 (or at least at a higher version than 3.3.6.) Since you've locked sass-rails at an earlier version, the dependent gem can't find what it needs.

If this is a new Rails app, I suggest reverting your sass-rails gem back to 4.0.3.

Is there any reason why you want an earlier version?

Comment: please take a look at my complete gems.

Comment: you mention that I should revert my sass-rails back to 4.0.4 - which is the version that I have.